# Sortable jquery rectangle in grid (relative dimensions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Hello I have a rectangle that I want to move inside a grid. The rectangle is a multiple of the grid cells. So width=100% and height=100% is 1 cell, while width=200% and height=200% is 4 cells.

Now I created a code with jquery-ui-sortable but it is not working for all the dimensions. For example width=100% and height=300% works fine but the opposite width=300% and height=100% is moving the rectangle in a wrong position with respect to the mouse pointer during dropping event.

Someone can explain me how to fix this issue and why the object is not placed where is dropped?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/enialisem/pen/dyoEBr)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
.container {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 50%; 
    padding:0;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableCell {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
  width: 12.5%;
  padding-bottom:12.5%;
  position: relative;
}
.rectangle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://sinclairorthodontics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Placeholder-2400px-1024x1024.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
} 


refreshTable();
function refreshTable()
{
    $('.divTableCell').sortable({
        connectWith: '.divTableCell',
        cursorAt: { top:30, left: 30 },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To add the following option in sortable:

```
tolerance:'pointer'
```